# Finite Differences for Boundary Value Problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

I was presented with the following equation that has to be solved using Finite Difference Method in MATLAB. However, I am very lost here. I can't really figure it out how to put this in a matrix and solve it.

$fu′=ϵu′′$

where $f$ & $ϵ$ are constants for $u(−1)=1$ and $u(1)=−1$

My understanding of the Finite Difference Method is that I need to calculate the derivative with numerical differentiation, but I don't know how to set it up so I can create a matrix that I can work with in MATLAB. Can you someone give me some guidence on how to setup that matrix? I am quite lost here.

Comment: No one explained to you what to do? No lectures? No recommended textbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a grid going from $-1$ to $1$ with N points, then define:

$$h=\frac{2}{N}$$

And approximate the derivatives, for example, using central differences:

$$u_n' \to \frac{u[-1+(n+1)h]-u[-1+(n-1)h]}{2h}$$

$$u_n'' \to \frac{u[-1+(n+2)h]-2u[-1+nh]+u[-1+(n-2)h]}{4h}$$

Now if $n=1,2,...,N$, you have exactly $N$ unknowns in the form $u_n=u[-1+nh]$, two of which are immediately found from the boundary conditions, the rest from the equation with the derivatives replaced as above.